# Unity3d How to find RawImage with name in code

Tags: unity-game-engine, rawimage

```
texture = tex;
GameObject.Find("Aciklama1L1").transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = tex;
```

I want change RawImage texture but it's not work.

Comment: Well few things to keep in mind: Do not confuse Find, with FindByTag, Find uses gameObject names! Also, I hope texture variable is a Texture2D, and finally, have you debuged if any part of the last lime of code is null? Like your Find is returning null? Also on StackOverflow try to get used to attach your console debugs ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solved] its not work because Gameobject is invisible, it cannot be found with find.